# I'm trying to install all the required modules for my project

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm just working on my personal project. I'm trying to install all the required modules for my project.

**Issues**

1. I'm trying to move all the install modules in my local to remote systems in *Virtual Environment*.
2. When i'm doing so, it again need to be reinstalled using `pip install <module> --force-reinstall`
3. I didn't want to install it again and again.

So, is there any alternative way that i can send all the modules in my *Virtual Environment* to remote system, without `pip install <module> --force-reinstall` re-installing them?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. Please read [ask].

Comment: I just edited your question to try to fix the grammar. The last sentence was unclear but I think I figured out what you mean. Could you check it please?

Comment: @Karl I don't think they're looking for a discussion, just the grammar was off. I've edited to try to fix it.

Comment: I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get a list of all modules and packages in my `venv` then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` when I need to install into a new `venv`.

Comment: Sorry for grammer mistake...

1. I just didn't want that my remote machine will install the modules again.
2. Trying to send all the modules as zip and written a code to unzip the modules.zip at remote system.
3. Now, by using setup.py its working. 
4. I have invoke the setup.py using **python setup.py install**.

Now, all things are working.
Thanks and my apology for my Grammer mistakes.